# Exclude particular file from GitHub search

Tags: github

I would like to know if and how you can exclude from the search results all the repositories that contain a certain type of file.

Specifically, I'm not interested in any kind of project that uses Composer and so I would like to exclude from the search results all the repositories that contain the `composer.json` file as they are many, occupy completely useless pages and pages that I will never open.

Comment: The GitHub documentation has some ways you can exclude words from search results. Does this help? https://help.github.com/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax/#exclude-certain-results

Comment: I know this syntax but not solved the problem

Comment: did you find out how to do it?

Comment: -filename:composer.json

Answer (score 26):

You can use qualifiers to exclude certain filenames from your search. To exclude `composer.json` from search results, you can do something like this:

```
-filename:composer.json
```

The `-` can be used with any qualifier to exclude results matching the qualifier.

This is what the GitHub documentation says:

> Another way you can narrow down search results is to exclude certain subsets. You can prefix any search qualifier with a - to exclude all results that are matched by that qualifier.

Here are some helpful links about searching code on GitHub:

- [Excluding results from your search](https://help.github.com/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax/#exclude-certain-results)
- [A list of qualifiers you can use when searching for code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/)

Comment: Thanks but not work. For example if i search php cms -filename:composer.json It also shows me the results that composer.json has in the file list.

Comment: Adriano, I have just tested doing a github search as [php cms -filename:composer.json] (I'm using brackets to indicate the exact search term), and that does not find composer.json files. Indeed, you take out the dash, it finds only those files. it does seem to work as it should. I realize your comments were from 2 years ago. I offer this as much for future readers who may have the issue and question if it really works.